# How do you create a layout with rectangular buttons on the top row?

Tags: android, layout

As in this image:

[image: a busy cat]

![two muppets][1]

where the buttons are Main, Favorites, and Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously a Tab Layout. Read [Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) and [this more clear example](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/11/17/tablayouttabhost-tutorial-for-android-reusing-layout/)

Answer (score 0):

check this:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Answer (score 0):

That is not the Button. It's Tab Bar that is Displayed at the Top instead of Bottom

[Tab Bar aligned Top](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you look at the Android Tab layout tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

HOWEVER please be aware that this tutorial uses the TabActivity class, which is deprecated.  The documentation for TabActivity contains a version done using Fragments, which is the way tabs should be done now: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

Note that if you are developing for older Android devices, you should download the v4 support library, which allows you to use Fragments on old API versions: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html